# Instantiate Prefab From Script Inside A Canvas

Tags: unity, c#

I am trying to instantiate a `Prefab` inside a `Canvas`. Right now, it keeps appearing behind the canvas. I was reading online and it said to set the parent of the `GameObject` you are trying to instantiate. However, I can't figure out how to get the `Canvas` component.

My hierarchy looks like this:

[image]

My `EnemyFormation` object has this script attached to it:

```
public class EnemySpawner : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject enemyPrefab;

    void Start () {
        Instantiate(enemyPrefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity);
        Debug.Log("Spawning enemy");
    }
}
```

I attach the prefab inside Unity editor. I tried adding this line under `Instantiate()`:

```
enemyPrefab.transform.SetParent(GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Canvas"), false);
```

However, I get an error saying it can't convert from `Unity.GameObject` to `Unity.Transform`.

How do I make the prefab appear inside the `Canvas` instead of behind it? Thanks in advance!

This is what it looks like when it creates it in-game: `Enemy_Orange3(Clone)` is created outside of the canvas and at the bottom left instead of the center. My camera is in the same position and is the same size of the canvas.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SetParent` like below. You have to use a another `GameObject` to instantiate and set the parent.

```
GameObject enemy = Instantiate(enemyPrefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;
enemy.transform.SetParent (GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Canvas").transform, false);
```

Setting parent is done with transforms of two objects.

Comment: It still creates the object outside of the canvas `Enemy_Orange3(Clone)`: https://zippy.gfycat.com/MemorableWaterloggedCoelacanth.gif. My `SetParent()` line looks exactly like yours.

Comment: Did you tag the canvas? Is your `enemyPrefab` an UI object? Also make the Boolean `true` to keep it's global orientation similar.

Comment: I think it's a UI object. When I click the prefab in Unity, it says Layer: UI in the Inspector. I set it to `true` but same results. I did tag the Canvas (Custom Tag).

Comment: Sorry about the other error, was my mistake. However, I am getting this: `Setting the parent of a transform which resides in a prefab is disabled to prevent data corruption. UnityEngine.Transform:SetParent(Transform, Boolean)`

Comment: Ooh, I fixed it. I had to use a temporary reference variable of type `GameObject` to set the parent. Basically: `GameObject enemy = Instantiate(enemyPrefab, new Vector3(0, 0, 0), Quaternion.identity) as GameObject;` then use `enemy` to set the parent. You can add it to your post if you want. Thanks for the help!

Comment: (y) was focusing on the error anyway.